# How many elements use for device to work with certain probability.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Hello I have exercise like this:

Some device is build from $n$ elements. Device works if at least **97%** of elements is working. Probability of each element breaking is $0.02$ . How many elements must be used when building device for it to work with probability **95% or more**?

What I understand from it:

**Not_enough_parts_is_broken** = **Device_is_working** = $CDF[BinomalDistribution[n, 0.02], 0.03n]$

Each part breaks independently with $0.02$ probability, and we want to have max 3% parts broken. So we add PDF from $<0, 0.03n)$

**Probability_that_device_works_with_n_elements = ?**
Should I just try some different values of $n$ now until I get one or could you help me with getting equation for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than it looks.  You can use your method to determine that n=500 will work.  However, there are numbers above n=500 that will not satisfy the condition.  Also, n=1 and n=2 will satisfy the condition.  With n=1, 100% of the parts will work with probability 98%.  With n=2, 100% of the parts will work with probability .98*.98 = 96.04%.

I used the free program called R to compute the values from 1 to 700 which work as follows:

```
> f = function(n) pbinom(.03*n,n,.02)
> which(f(1:700) >= .95)
  [1]   1   2 500 501 502 503 504 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544
 [19] 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584
 [37] 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617
 [55] 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644
 [73] 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662
 [91] 663 664 665 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681
[109] 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699
[127] 700
```

You can see the issue is that 3% of 500 is exactly 15, but as we move to 501, we can still only afford to have 15 defective, but that has lower probability out of a higher number.  It is less than 95% until we get to 534 where we can allow 16.  That works until we get to 545 where it fails again.  Then it works again at 600 where we can allow 17, and so on.  It's not until we get to 667 and above that this effect terminates as you can see by the lack of a gap below 700 where we can first allow 21, so it should be contiguous beyond that.

Comment: It's seemed intuitive for me that there some number after which the probability is always smaller and it's kinda stated in excercise. But I am suprised that 1 and 2 are also here. Thanks. I've learned a little about R when I was exploring machine learning. Some of these ready functions and plotting options are really neat.

Comment: For $n=1$ the probability the single element is working is $0.98$; for $n=2$ the probability both elements are working is $0.9604$.  Both of these probabilities exceed $95\%$ which is what you asked for.  For $n=3$ the probability all three elements are working is $0.941192$ which is less the $95\%$ and so not high enough